# Dynamically add all pictureboxes to list?

Tags: c#, list, addition, items

I'm trying to create a list of all pictureboxes named "pictureBox" + x. I've tried some different methods I found online, but they didn't work :(

Simple "code":

```
int x = 1;

List<PictureBox> list= new List<PictureBox>();


if (there is a picturebox named "pictureBox" + x) {
    list.Add("pictureBox" + x as type PictureBox);
    x = x + 1;
}
else
    Stop running this code;
```

So x will be increasing until there is no more pictureboxes found. How can I do this? Thanks :)

Edit:
I'm using a winform in visual studio and I tried to use

```
list.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + x));
```

but I can't get that to work.

Comment: Can you at least say few words about what different methods you found online and tried, and their outcome..? Also, where are all these picture boxes supposed to live? on a Form? as its n fields? or something else? Not sure what is the scenario / bigger picture here..

Comment: There is no general way to get control by it's name. The solution depends on at least the platform (winform, WPF, ASP.NET, etc), maybe depends on how you created and display those `PictureBox`s too... and these information are missing!!

Comment: I agree with har07. one sooution could be to use a Dictionary<?, PictureBox> so you could simply get rid of searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
  //do stuff
}
```

This will give you the PictureBoxes. And check its name inside the foreach loop. Add the list if it fits your conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I just added "if (pb.Name.StartsWith("pictureBox"))" and it worked :)